# Throw error if global variable is not pre-defined?

Tags: php, global-variables

This is probably a long shot.

I wrote some code in PHP:

```
function test_dummy()
{
    global $this_is_a_test;
    $this_is_a_test = "test in progress";
}
error_log($this_is_a_test);
```

However, I *did not* define the `$this_is_a_test` global variable before calling `test_dummy()`. Yet the string `"test in progress"` is still printed to the log on line 6.

I know why this happens, but my question is: is there a PHP setting to make a function complain/crash if a global variable it expects to already exist is not defined beforehand? My project is large-ish and keeping track of where every single variable is defined and used is getting to be difficult. Spawning an error would be helpful.

Comment: IMHO you should actually spend the time removing all uses of `global` and start working out how this can be done in a more *friendly* way.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get rid of the globals, but I'll leave that for another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` keyword is a scope modifier. When you declare `global $this_is_a_test;` it creates a variable with global scope if it does not exist. 
So it is working perfectly.

For more details check [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).